# Rails 4 Autocomplete Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete

I am trying to implement an autocomplete form in my rails application.

So far I have gone through the following installation steps.

Gemfile added:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rails4-autocomplete'
```

Application.js added:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

In my models, I have a Job and a Company. A `Job belongs_to Company` and a `Company has_many Jobs`.

In my routes.rb I have:

```
resources :companies
resources :jobs do
  get :autocomplete_company_name, :on => :collection
end
```

Jobs controller added to top:

```
autocomplete :company, :name
```

All a Job consists of is a Date, and then foreign keys to tables such as Company, Contact, Jobsite, etc. On the Jobs new _form I have:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :date, :value=>Time.now %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value=>current_user.id %>

   <%= f.fields_for :company, @company do |company| %>
      <%= company.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_company_name_jobs_path %>
```

I am able to render the autocomplete field on my form, but when i start typing, nothing comes up. Home Depot is one of my dummy companies in my test database, but you can see when i type "Ho" nothing appears to autocomplete.

[image]

The page source for the autocomplete field i am rendering appears like so:

```
<input data-autocomplete="/jobs/autocomplete_company_name" type="text" name="job[company][name]" id="job_company_name" />
```

I have been following the documentation and instructions found here: https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete

Is there something I am missing? Such as some javascript files I am not including or a script/function I need to be running in my application.js? Or a javascript_include_tag in my application.html?

I am new to using jQuery and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

After searching online for more examples, I found the answer.

First, I was slightly off. The `autocomplete :company, :name` needed to be in my Company Controller, and the `get :autocomplete_company_name, :on => :collection` needed to be nested in my `companies` resources.

I don't know why their documentation for their Gem would be missing this, but, in order to make the gem work I had to create my own js.erb file and add a javascript function.

In `app/assets/javascripts` I created `company.js.erb` and added the following function:

```
$(function() {
    var companies = <%Company.all.collect{|company| company.name}%>
    $( "#jobCompany" ).autocomplete({
      source: companies
    });
  });
```

That was all that was missing and once I restored the server everything was working as it should.

Note, if you want to have the autocomplete suggestion be formatted nicely, then in the `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` add `*= require jquery-ui`